# File upload input controls not working for dynamic forms generated from laravel controllers and jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I was wondering someone could help me with this problem I'm having. I'm pulling a form/view from a controller and loading it via json response in laravel. Here is the code below....

```
$form = view('myview);
return response()->json([
            'loadedform' => $form,
            'price_per_day' => $price_per_day,
        ]);
```

Now when I'm pulling the form all of the form controls come up normally however the file inputs aren't working for example these lines of code don't work to pull files for uploads...

```
<div class="custom-file">
   <input type="file" class="custom-file-input @error('file'.$counter.'') is-invalid @enderror" id="file{{ $counter }}" aria-describedby="fileAdd{{ $counter }}" name="file{{ $counter }}">
<label class="custom-file-label" for="file{{ $counter }}">Choose Photo</label>                                
</div>
```

None of the file uploads are working. However if I enter this code manually instead of trying to pull the form dynamically from a controller it works fine.
To clarify the entire form is loading fine from the controller. However when I try to use the file inputs to upload a file. The file or pic I select doesn't even come up on the input box. 
Any ideas what the hell may be the issue?

Regards,

Darren

Comment: What means "not working"? What happens exactly? Try to look into the rendered HTML output and check for errors.

Comment: The entire form is loading fine. However when I try to use the file inputs to upload a file. The file or pic I select doesn't even come up on the input box.

Comment: If you have multiple file in your form, don't forget to name field file[] to handle multiple items into an array for php.

Comment: @FredericKlee No that's not the problem.